# How to Fix Malformed Whitespace Separator using C#

Tags: c#

I have the following string:

```
string testString = ",,,The,,,boy,,,kicked,,,the,,ball";
```

I want to remove the unwanted commas and have the sentence as this (simply printed to the console):

```
The boy kicked the ball
```

I tried the below code:

```
    string testString = ",,,The,,,boy,,,kicked,,,the,,ball";
    string manipulatedString = testString.Replace(",", " "); //line 2
    Console.WriteLine(manipulatedString.Trim() + "\n");

    string result = Regex.Replace(manipulatedString, "  ", " ");
    Console.WriteLine(result.TrimStart());
```

However, I end up with a result with double whitespaces as so:

```
The  boy  kicked  the  ball
```

It kind of makes sense why I am getting such an anomalous output because in line 2 I am saying that for every comma (,) character, replace that with whitespace and it will do that for every occurrence.

What's the best way to solve this?

Comment: The output is not anomalous because `String.Replace` is behaving exactly as it's defined.

Comment: Without Regex :            string testString = ",,,The,,,boy,,,kicked,,,the,,ball";
            string[] words = testString.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            string output = string.Join(" ", words);

Comment: For the second argument of `Replace`, just supply an empty string instead of a space. `var manipulatedString = testString.Replace(",","");` Ta da

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a simple solution using Split and Join

```
string testString = ",,,The,,,boy,,,kicked,,,the,,ball";
var splitted = testString.Split(new char[] {','}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
string result = string.Join(" ", splitted);
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use regex to replace the pattern `,+` (one or more occurrences of a comma) by a whitespace.

```
var replacedString = Regex.Replace(testString, ",+", " ").Trim();
```

Added `Trim` to remove white spaces at beginning/end as I assume you want to remove them.